# Spring Error in creating bean with name propertyPlaceholderConfigurer defined in Classpath

Tags: java, spring

*Hi Experts*

We are loading the beans with xml files in class path using the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. **It finds and loads the xml files from classpath** ,but in one of xml files which has propertyPlaceholderConfigurer  **bean referring the property file from classpath**. It throws the null pointer exception with unable to create the propertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean.

**Not sure whether it reads the property file even though it is classpath as it can read other xml files?**
Any chance of property file having corrupted data?
Any clues on what could be the issue ?

```
Error creating bean with name 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' defined in class path resource [ws.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.StatelessBeanO.initialize(StatelessBeanO.java:375)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.BMStatelessBeanOFactory.create(BMStatelessBeanOFactory.java:45)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1031)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSHome.createBeanO(EJSHome.java:1141)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.UncachedActivationStrategy.atActivate(UncachedActivationStrategy.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.activator.Activator.activateBean(Activator.java:599)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvokeActivate(EJSContainer.java:3964)
    at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.preInvoke(EJSContainer.java:3269)
    at com.ibm.websphere.scheduler.EJSRemoteStatelessMeFBatchHandler_fb00fe87.process(EJSRemoteStatelessMeFBatchHandler_fb00fe87.java:27)
    at com.ibm.websphere.scheduler._TaskHandler_Stub.process(_TaskHandler_Stub.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.tasks.BeanTaskInfoWork.doWork(BeanTaskInfoWork.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.executeTaskWithNotification(AlarmListener.java:796)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.access$700(AlarmListener.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.doWork(AlarmListener.java:427)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener$TaskWork.run(AlarmListener.java:213)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:782)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.ExecutionContextImpl.go(ExecutionContextImpl.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fireTask(AlarmListener.java:1401)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.AlarmListener.fired(AlarmListener.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.callListenerMethod(AlarmImpl.java:340)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.timer.GenericTimer.run(GenericTimer.java:216)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.J2EEContext.run(J2EEContext.java:1150)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.AlarmImpl.runListenerAsCJWork(AlarmImpl.java:175)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.fireAlarm(_Alarm.java:333)
    at com.ibm.ws.asynchbeans.am._Alarm.run(_Alarm.java:230)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' defined in class path resource [ws.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:516)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:363)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
```

Comment: Which version of Spring is this?  The line numbers don't quite match with the source I'm looking at, which is 3.0.4.RELEASE.

Comment: Can you post the xml definition for your PropertyPlaceholdConfigurer?

Answer (score 0):

**new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(a.xml ,b.xml,c.xml);**

**returns null pointer exceptio**n because of propertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean defined iin c.xml ,which refers the property file in classpath.

Comment: The issue got resolved when i upgraded to Spring 2.5.6 , this is the compatability issue between Spring2.5.3 and JRE1.6 which comes with WAS7.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your Spring libraries. If they are with mixed/mismatched version then remove the old version jars and replace with new version jars.